# how print lines between 3 & 6 lines using sed?

Tags: sed, scripting

```
1 ajar 45000
2 Sunil 25000
3 varoom 50000
4 Amit 47000
5 tanru 15000
6 Deepak 23000
7 Sunil 13000
8 sattvic 80000
```

I did it using awk. I want using sed command

`$ awk 'NR==3, NR==6 {print NR,$0}' employee.txt`

Comment: You could try like: `awk 'FNR>3 && FNR<6; FNR==6{exit}' Input_file`

Comment: Try `cat -n file | sed -ne '3,6p'`

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sed -n '3,6p' employee.txt
```

- `-n` tells sed to not print each line;
- `3,6` is an "address", it tells sed to only apply the following command to the given range of lines;
- `p` tells sed to print the line.